# Female dog keeps peeing inside at night

Tags: dogs, behavior, toilet-training

My female dog keeps peeing inside at night, always at the same spot, in the middle of the living room, 2 meters from her own bed. I don't understand why and here are some details of the context:

- 2 years old, weighs around 17kg, healthy
- Rescue dog, comes from Romania where the pound has probably been tough with her. Been transferred to an animal shelter here in France when she was 1 year old.
- Very fearful, any sound or sudden move can make her scamper away.
- Not aggressive, not dominant (humans nor dogs).
- Has been with me for only 4 months.

**Note :** She pooped/peed inside the first weeks at home, but then she stopped for months. It's been 3 to 4 weeks since she started peeing inside again. I've tried to take her out at 22:00 until I actually see her peeing, then reward her, then empty her bowl of water before going to sleep. When I wake up at 07:00 she did it again.

Any advice from behaviorists?

**UPDATE:** Last night I tried to make her sleep inside our room. I saw that technique on Youtube (dogs don't pee if it's too close from where they sleep). It worked so I am probably going to keep it that way for a few weeks. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Now that it has been 4 months since I posted here, and about 3 months (roughly) without  an accident, here is how I did it :

1. I made her sleep in my room at night, **door closed** for a whole week.
2. Every night before sleep time, I let her out and trained her to pee on demand (*you'll find out how to do it bellow*).
3. A week later, she peed again in the living room
4. I made her sleep in my room for a week again.
5. **[REPEAT UNTIL IT'S OK]**

**How to make your dog pee on demand :**

1. Go out with your dog on a spot where you want him to pee every night (it's important to set up a routine).
2. Ask him to pee with the word/phrase you want, (eg. "go pee !"). Again it's important to use the same word(s) every time.
3. Stay still until he does it. If your dog is not sniffing the floor or walking around anymore, motivate him by saying the words again with more enthusiasm.
4. When he does it, reward, as usual, by greeting/petting/giving a treat to him.
5. If you did it in your own garden, ask him gently if he wants to go back inside. If not, **do not insist**. Let him outside for 5-10 more minutes and go back there to get him back in. If you have to go down the street to walk your dog, **do not head back home** as soon as your dog is finished. This is important because if you do so, your dog will think that **peeing = walk is over**.